# Is VkDescriptorPoolSize struct really needed when creating descriptor pools?

Tags: vulkan

I'm creating descriptor pool with `poolSizeCount == 0` and `pPoolSizes == nullptr` and i still can allocate various number of descriptors of any type. There are no validation errors on Linux, only on Windows (but code works).

Another case: i'm providing VkDescriptorPoolSize with only 1 VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, but can allocate more VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER or even descriptors of other types (in this case errors don't occur on both Linux and Windows).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

It is not technically invalid usage to exceed the pool limits in general:

> If a call to `vkAllocateDescriptorSets` would cause the total number of descriptor sets allocated from the pool to exceed the value of `vkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo::maxSets` used to create `pAllocateInfo->descriptorPool`, then the allocation **may** fail due to lack of space in the descriptor pool. Similarly, the allocation **may** fail due to lack of space if the call to `vkAllocateDescriptorSets` would cause the number of any given descriptor type to exceed the sum of all the `descriptorCount` members of each element of `VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo::pPoolSizes` with a member equal to that type.

Note the use of the word "**may**", which allows implementations to fail but doesn't *require* them to do so. This means that you're supposed to stay within those limits, but nobody's going to stop you if you exceed them and get away with it.

Now, it *is* a violation of valid usage to pass no sizes at all:

> `poolSizeCount` must be greater than 0

And the appropriate layer should catch that. But outside of layers, you just achieve undefined behavior. Which can be "appears to work".

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Will try to pay more attention to spec terms.

Comment: @DenisBelov In the future, problems like these may be checked by [Best Practices Validation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.1.126.0/windows/best_practices.html), although validation checks for this particular issue are [not yet implemented](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/24).